# Unable to understand a snippet of code, need guidance

Tags: java, arrays

Unable to understand the snippet of code shown below, need help:

/*compute average of 10 numbers*/

```
class    ArrayAvg{

public   static   void  main (String [] s)
{/*enter code here*/


     double   numbers[] = {10.5, 20.6, 30.8, 15.5, 17.3, 25.5, 27.2, 20, 30, 18.5};


    byte   ctr;
    double   sum=0, avg;

    System.out.println("list of numbers is");

    for  (ctr=0; ctr<10; ctr++){

        System.out.println(numbers[ctr]);
        sum = sum + numbers[ctr];    
    }

    avg = sum/10;
    System.out.println(" /* Average of above numbers is */  "  + avg);

    }  //main

}  //class
```

> I expect the output 21.59

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Start by learning how this site works, and how to properly format your code so that it appears human readable.

Comment: Run your code under debugger, step by step, watch over variables and their values, and you'll understand logic of algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You get the average of the numbers contained in the "numbers" array.

**Long answer**

The ctr (counter) variable goes through the array's indexes.

> numbers[0] equals 10.5
>
> numbers[1] equals 20.6
>
> numbers[2] equals 30.8
>
> and so on

Each element is added to the sum variable and then the list's avg (average) is calculated below.

The list given has a length of so the hardcoded numbers work for this example. 
It is better though to let the program figure out these numbers so that mistakes are easily avoided.

```
for  (ctr=0; ctr<10; ctr++){
```

can be replaced with

```
for (ctr = 0; numbers.size(); ctr++){
```

So that all elements are accessed no matter the array's size in case you make changes.

Also

```
avg = sum/10;
```

should be

```
avg = sum/numbers.size();
```

for the same reason